# Replace Strings Using Sed And Regex

Tags: regex, string, bash, sed, replace

I'm trying to uncomment file content using sed but with regex (for example: [0-9]{1,5})

```
# one two 12
# three four 34
# five six 56
```

The following is working:

```
sed -e 's/# one two 12/one two 12/g' /file
```

However, what I would like is to use regex pattern to replace all matches without entering numbers but keep the numbers in the result.

Comment: How do you define "matches"? Which lines do you want to uncomment and how do you decide that?

Comment: it should only uncomment text witch contains numbers.

Comment: this is an old question. But it helped me understand `sed`. I have made a significant change tot he Highest score answer (edits in review) and ask if @starryknight64 please review and choose an  answer.

Comment: @dank8 I can't select an answer as I'm not the author of this question, I've only edited it for formatting. tangi is though.

Comment: @starryknight64 oops sorry my bad.

Comment: this is an old question. But it helped me understand sed. I have made a significant change tot he Highest score answer (edits in review) and ask if @tangi please review and choose an answer.

Answer (score 28):

For complying sample question, simply

```
sed 's/^# //' file
```

will suffice, but if there is a need to remove the comment only on some lines containing a particular regex, then you could use conditionnal **address**:

```
sed '/regex/s/^# //' file
```

So every lines containing `regex` will be *uncomented* (if line *begin* with a `#`)

... where `regex` could be `[0-9]` as:

```
sed '/[0-9]/s/^# //' file
```

will remove `#`  at begin of every  lines containing a number, or

```
sed '/[0-9]/s/^# \?//' file
```

to make first space not *needed*: `#one two 12`, or even

```
sed '/[0-9]$/s/^# //' file
```

will remove `#`  at begin of lines containing a number as last character. Then

```
sed '/12$/s/^# //' file
```

will remove `#`  at begin of lines ended by `12`. Or

```
sed '/\b\(two\|three\)\b/s/^# //' file
```

will remove `#`  at begin of lines containing **word** `two` or `three`.

Comment: I like this; it's a bit clearer about the intent.  (You don't want to "replace # + some stuff + a digit + other stuff, with everything but the `#`"; you want to "remove the `#` on lines that contain digits".)  For `regex`, you could say `[0-9]` to have it only affect lines with digits in them, or `[0-9]$` if the number has to be at the end.

Answer (score 9):

```
sed -e 's/^#\s*\(.*[0-9].*\)$/\1/g' filename
```

should do it.

Comment: the issue here is that this will uncomment everything including text without numbers.

Comment: Could by written: `sed -e '/[0-9]/s/^# *//' filename`! See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074855/1765658)

Comment: Don't forget to add `-i` to replace in place, directly in the file, but without that just to check the output

Answer (score 2):

Is the `-i` option for replacement in the respective file not necessary? I get to remove leading `#` by using the following:

```
sed -i "s/^# \(.*\)/\1/g" file
```

In order to uncomment only those commented lines that end on a sequence of at least one digit, I'd use it like this:

```
sed -i "s/^# \(.*[[:digit:]]\+$\)/\1/g" file
```

This solution requires commented lines to begin with one space character (right behind the `#`), but that should be easy to adjust if not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want those lines uncommented which contain numbers, you can use this:

```
sed -e 's/^#\s*\(.*[0-9]+.*\)/\1/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `sed` command will uncomment lines containing numbers:

```
sed 's/^#\s*\(.*[0-9]\+.*$\)/\1/g' file
```

Answer (score -1):

I find it. thanks to all of you

```
echo "# one two 12" | grep "[0-9]" | sed 's/# //g'
```

or

```
cat file | grep "[0-9]" | sed 's/# //g'
```

Comment: These solutions delete lines which don't contain digits but that were not already uncommented.  Maybe there are no such lines (not even any blank lines?), but it arguably isn't wholly appropriate behaviour.