# How to change *** to \textbf with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I export results from my analysis into a table in Latex. I would like to be able to change all coefficients that are significant to `***, **, *` to bold face text `\textbf`. This requires me to search with `sed` and change the stars to wrap around the coefficient.

I want to change `0.047$^{***}$` to `\textbf{0.047}`

I've been trying, `sed /s/$^{***}$/}`, but this is only remove `$^{***}$`.

How do I insert `\textbf{` at the beginning of the number and a closing bracket `}` at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should [learn about regexes](https://regexone.com/) and see [manpage for sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt).

Then, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074855/2116001), and [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/aHLuZD/2), you can do:

```
sed -r 's/([0-9\.]+)\$\^\{\*{1,3}\}\$/\\textbf{\1}/g' filename
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I do `echo 0.4$^{***}$ | sed -e 's/([0-9\.]+)\$\^\{\*{1,3}\}\$/\\textbf{\1}/g'` I get an error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 44: Invalid content of \{\}
`

Comment: my bad, you have to use `sed -r` and not `sed -e`